# unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, django

I have this error, could you help me? You need to subtract the "quantity" value from the "Pedido" - "stock" model of the "Articulo" model, then save the stock result.

in line:    articulo.stock -= pedido.cantidad

```
 def Update_stock(request, id_pedido, cod_experto):
 if request.method == 'GET':
   pedido = Pedido.objects.get(id=id_pedido)
   articulo = Articulo.objects.get(pk=cod_experto)
   articulo.stock -= pedido.cantidad
   articulo.save()
 return render(request, 'admindata.html', {'pedido':pedido, 'articulo':articulo})
```

models.py:

```
class Pedido(models.Model):
articulo       = models.ForeignKey('Articulo')
fecha_pedido   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True, blank=True)
cantidad       = models.IntegerField(blank=True)



def __str__(self):
    return '{}'.format(self.especialidad, self.articulo, self.cantidad, self.estado)


class Articulo(models.Model):
cod_experto = models.CharField(max_length=999, primary_key=True, blank=True)
nombre      = models.CharField(max_length=999, blank=True)
on_delete=models.CASCADE)
stock       = models.CharField(max_length=999, blank=True)
```

Comment: `articulo.stock` is a string, probably.

Comment: i cant add anything more than what @Jean-FrançoisFabre has said. its clearly a string, it says so in the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message means that `articulo.stock` is inadvertently assigned a *str* instead of a number.

In the model, *stock* is defined as a `CharField`.  Probably, it should be some numeric type such as `IntegerField()`.